# Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1 using telnet

Tags: telnet

I have a new Ubuntu install where I am not able to connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1 or using my computer name.

```
 telnet localhost
```

[tried all/no port numbers]

returns

```
 telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Is there any configuration I need to do to make this work? Would it be disabled by default??

Comment: I think that you have installed telnet correctly. Restart telnet: `sudo /etc/init.d/inetd restart` and then chek if it's working with `telnet localhost`

Answer (score 2):

Telnet is not a secure way of connecting and it is disabled by default. Use ssh for that; however, install the package `openssh-server` first.

Comment: You could use `sudo apt-get install telnetd` to install the telnet-daemon, but there is a very good reason not to do so - it's unsecure.